# Migrating project to .net6 getting issue

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, cmake, .net-6.0

Below Code works fine for Xamarin Projects:

```
set(DEMO_MONO_BASE "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current"
                  CACHE STRING "Path to Mono for csharp bindings")

set(DEMO_XAMARIN_BASE "/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current"
                     CACHE STRING "Path to Xamarin for csharp bindings")

set(CSC ${DEMO_MONO_BASE}/bin/csc)

add_custom_target(sea ALL
                      ${CSC} -o- -out:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/abc/abc.dll
                      -res:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/xyz/abc.a
                      -res:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libxyz_client.a
                      ${CSHARP_FILES} -target:library -unsafe
                      -reference:${DEMO_XAMARIN_BASE}/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll
                      DEPENDS ${CSHARP_PROCESSED} xyz_swig)
```

I am trying to generate dll for net6.0 version. But Getting below error.
Added following configuration for net6

#reference flag
set(SEA_DOTNET_BASE "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Ref/16.4.7067/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.iOS.dll")

set_target_properties(${this_target} PROPERTIES DOTNET_SDK
"Microsoft.NET.Sdk" DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK "net7.0")

**Issue:**

The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

What could be equivalent path for the below commands in dotnet :

DEMO_MONO_BASE  and DEMO_XAMARIN_BASE

Comment: `-reference:${DEMO_XAMARIN_BASE}/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll` this looks suspicious. You are still referring to Xamarin.iOS which is not net6.0-ios compatible. You shouldn't be referring to anything Mono nor Xamarin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Cheesebaron, Do you have any idea what need to pass for net6.0, since i am looking path for dll for a refernce.

Comment: Do you have actual iOS specific code in there?

Comment: @Cheesebaron  yes , I have objective c code. After adding the paths below, i am getting the above issue.


set(SEA_DOTNET_BASE "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Ref/16.4.7067/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.iOS.dll")
set_target_properties(${this_target} PROPERTIES DOTNET_SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK "net7.0")